# Displaying rasters in a folder | QGIS 3.0.3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I have a satellite image. And in the folder where this picture is stored, it is well displayed.

[image]

But when I divide it with the help of script into parts and save in a separate folder, then get such a display of parts in the folder.
[image]

---

[image]

Here is the script:

```
# grid - grid lying on the satellite image


for i in range(grid.featureCount()):
        grid.select(i)
        OUTPUT = 'LC08_L1TP_155016_20180203_20180203_01_RT_B1_{}'.format(i+1)
        parameters = {'INPUT': 'D:/Study/PROJECT/Storage scene/LC08_L1TP_155016_20180203_20180203_01_RT_B1/LC08_L1TP_155016_20180203_20180203_01_RT_B1.TIF', 
                        'MASK': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(grid.name(), True),
                        'NODATA' : 0, 
                        'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 
                        'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 
                        'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 
                        'OPTIONS' : '', 
                        'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 
                        'OUTPUT' : 'D:/Study/PROJECT/Storage clip/LC08_L1TP_155016_20180203_20180203_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_155016_20180203_20180203_01_RT_B1/' + OUTPUT + '.TIF'}  
        processing.run('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer', parameters)
        grid.removeSelection()
```

Maybe it depends on the parameters?

How to fix it?

---

In QGIS this is shown normally.
[image]

But in the folder it looks like this:

[image]

How to make a part in the folder displayed normally, as in QGIS?

In the future, OpenCV will use these parts of the satellite image to determine the images. ("В будущем OpenCV будет использовать эти части изображения спутника для определения образов." in Russian)

Comment: And what is the problem? That nodata areas appear white instead of black?

Comment: Do you mean the thumbnail images in the Windows directory view? That does not feel like a GIS problem really but use gdalinfo for both kind of images and find out what is the difference.